# NHibernate tries to query in a nonexistent column

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Using fluent NHibernate, I have mapped an Entity with a Id column(UsuarioConta), and this entity refs another Entity (MoedaValor) as a component, that it does not have an Id column. But when I try to query UsuarioConta, it returns me an error: `Invalid column name 'Id'.`

Looking to NHibernate query, I could see that NHibernate tries to query in a nonexistent column in MoedaValor table, as if I had referred a Id column - that i didn't.

My map:

```
public class UsuarioContaMap
{
    public UsuarioContaMap()
    {
        Table("UsuarioConta");

        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity()

        References<Usuario>(x => x.Usuario)
           .Column("IdUsuario")
           .ForeignKey("FK_UsuarioConta_Usuario").Nullable();

        HasMany<UsuarioContaMovimentacao>(x => x.Movimentacoes)
            .KeyColumn("IdUsuarioConta")
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_UsuarioContMov_UsuarioCont")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

        HasMany<MoedaValor>(x => x.Saldos)
            .Table("UsuarioSaldo")
            .KeyColumn("IdUsuarioConta")
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_UsuarioSaldo_UsuarioConta")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Join()
            .Component(x =>
                           {
                               x.References(y => (Moeda)y.Moeda)
                                  .Column("IdMoeda")
                                  .ForeignKey("FK_UsuarioSaldo_Moeda");

                               x.Map(y => y.Valor);
                           });

    }
}
```

The query that returns error:

> select movimentac2_.Id as col_0_0_, movimentac3_.Id as col_1_0_, **saldos4_.Id as col_2_0_**, usuario0_.IdPessoa as col_3_0_, usuario0_.IdPessoa as col_4_0_, movimentac2_.Id as Id275_0_, movimentac3_.Id as Id275_1_, movimentac2_.Valor as Valor275_0_, movimentac2_.Tipo as Tipo275_0_, movimentac2_.Data as Data275_0_, movimentac2_.IdMoeda as IdMoeda275_0_, movimentac2_.IdUsuarioConta as IdUsuari6_275_0_, movimentac3_.Valor as Valor275_1_, movimentac3_.Tipo as Tipo275_1_, movimentac3_.Data as Data275_1_, movimentac3_.IdMoeda as IdMoeda275_1_, movimentac3_.IdUsuarioConta as IdUsuari6_275_1_ from Usuario usuario0_ inner join Pessoa usuario0_1_ on usuario0_.IdPessoa=usuario0_1_.Id, UsuarioConta usuariocon1_ left outer join UsuarioContaMovimentacao movimentac2_ on usuariocon1_.Id=movimentac2_.IdUsuarioConta left outer join UsuarioContaMovimentacao movimentac3_ on usuariocon1_.Id=movimentac3_.IdUsuarioConta left outer **join UsuarioSaldo saldos4_** on usuariocon1_.Id=saldos4_.IdUsuarioConta where usuario0_.Perfil<>@p0 and usuario0_.Perfil<>@p1 and usuariocon1_.IdUsuario=usuario0_.IdPessoa

I have no complex query trying to get the result, so i think the problem is in the map. There is some error on it?

Comment: Because this query is being encapsulated outside of Hibernate, you need to check your function that calls the columns by their respective IDs. See what values are being populated and work backwards from there.

Comment: Even if theEntity MoedaValor has not any Id Variable? Also, the only comparisson that I do in query is using Usuario entity, not MoedaValor

Comment: I may have the method slightly off, but if Hibernate as a RDBMS is worth its salt,then it should have a table that lists for columns to each table by its ID. Meaning at worst Hibernate is not an RDBMS (having missing/extra columns would violate referential integrity), or likely something in your application code that is off. So verify from the application down to the RDBMS where the issue is. Feel free to get the list of columns Hibernate recognizes on the table (query Hibernate directly), but verify this off what your method returns.

Comment: @clifton_h NHibernate is not a RDBMS it's an ORM.  All the mappings to table columns are done in the mapping files which the person posing the question has included.

Comment: what does the mapping for MoedaValor look like?

Comment: MoedaValor has no map, since i used as component. Is it necessary if only this Entity uses MoedaValor?

Answer (score 0):

You have not given an columnname to the Id explicitly. So change this:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity()
```

To this:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ColumnName")
```

Where "ColumnName" is the name of the primary key column.